# Goutte, how can the site see i am a robot?

Tags: php, symfony, web-crawler, goutte

It doesn't matter whether I use Firefox or GoogleBot, the site still sees me as a bot.

I am trying to create a crawler using Goutte. The website have a blocking system for crawlers, but I can't figure out how to avoid it. This is my current code:

```
require_once 'includes/goutte.phar';
use Goutte\Client;
$client = new Client();
$client->setHeader('User-Agent', "Googlebot");
$crawler = $client->request('GET', 'http://www.example.com');
echo $crawler->filter('')->text();
```

As you can see I have changed the user-agent, and I have tested that it is changed correctly by crawling a local file, that logged the user agents.

Still the site somehow recognize me as a bot. Any ideas?

Comment: You're using the UA string "googlebot" and wondering how it knows you're a bot? Common sense: zero.

Comment: @Kolink - that's a bit harsh...nah, you're right :)

Comment: It doesnt matter what i use.

Comment: If the site is smart, it will use a whitelist approach to approve non-bots. If you use a valid UA and it still fails, it may be looking for another piece of information (such as a cookie). Kind of sounds like they don't want to be crawled.

Comment: Make sure your client is accepting cookies and sending them back with subsequent requests. Other than that, contact the site's administrators and ask pretty-please. They probably block bots for a reason.

Comment: While you ask this question, the website owner is asking how to identify a crawler and block it. Guess who is getting more answers.

Comment: It might be finding out that your requests are from a bot based on the number of requests. Perhaps also you need to visit a landing page and get a cookie prior to visiting the page you are targetting - the good news is that Goutte will do the cookie bit for you. Just see what happens in an ordinary browser, and try to replicate that - headers and cookies included.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it describes an immoral or illegal behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the firefox browser or just its user agent string?
If you haven't used the firefox browser, then do that and use something like the firebug addon ('Net' panel) or Tamperdata addon or Wireshark to capture the details of a request that results in a successful response.

If you can't get a successful response using firefox then it's unlikely to be blocking bots only.

If you can then replicate the request which resulted in a successful response.

You might also say what you mean by the "site still sees me as a bot" - exactly what response do you get?

Answer (score 0):

Sniff it with wireshark and check the HTTP headers.